# Overlaying SpatialLines by SpatialPolygons in R

Tags: r, spatial

I have a `SpatialLines` object representing roads and a `SpatialPolygons` object 
containing cities.

I'd like to know how to overlay a `SpatialLines` object by a `SpatialPolygons` 
object in R.

I'd like to know the Lines that passes over the two cities and which cities in?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, overlays of spatial objects are handled by the `over` function from the `sp` package. In the Methods section of the documentation of `over` (`?over`) there is a list of methods for `over`, which does not include the combination of `Lines` and `Polygons`. Luckily, the documentation of `over` says that by installing the `rgeos` package these kind of methods are made available.

Answer (score 3):

You need the rgeos package which wraps the GEOS library of geometry operations.

Then probably gIntersection or gIntersects will do what you want.